# IIS behaviour with JS files, transfer paused

Tags: windows, iis, website, javascript, windows-server-2003

This is a tough one, in all my years I've never seen it. The setup is windows 2003 r2, running IIS, MVC 1, asp.net 3.5. I have a website, which is viewable on the server itself and renders correctly. However, when you access it remotely the site transfers roughly half it's contents and then gets stuck downloading some javascript files. Browser stays in "transferring data". I'm mystified. Anyone got any pointers to help me from pulling out all my hair?

Comment: Here's a bit more information, it appears to be something to do with the wildcard MVC ISAPI filter. If I remove the wildcard mappign in IIS the default page renders, but not the MVC pages.

Comment: Okay, here's a bit more detail, which makes this even stranger! the site works fine with MVC ISAPI filter on wildcard, but only in Internet explorer. All the other browsers never fully render the page (firefox and chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler to watch the requests come out of the browser.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Also sometimes the content type is not set correctly, but really it sounds like the app itself is broken or needs IIS 7.x to run correctly.

Comment: It's still a mystery why this isn't working. It works okay on another win 2003 box, so it's something to do with the config... Anyway, I'll just build another machine, it doesn't seem like something anyone else has come across.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off TCP Checksum Task Offloading:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/904946

I had problems similar to this on a 2003 instance under XenServer.